# boolean recursion

Tags: java, recursion

trying to write a boolean method that tells if someone is a decendant of someone...but can't seem to do it. of course, the object is a descendant if it's a child...or the descendant of a child.

```
public boolean isDescendant(member x){
    if (children.contains(x)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

but where or how do i insert:

```
for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++){
    isDescendant(children.get(i));
}
```

thanks!

Comment: You haven't said whether the nodes form a cyclic graph or a DAG / tree, and whether a child node has a link to its parent node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walking trees is very slow downwards (from the root to the leaves). Consider this implementation for the is-ancestor check:

```
/**
 * Checks whether the given node is an ancestor of this node.
 */
public boolean isDescendantOf(Node ancestor) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(ancestor, "Ancestor");
    if (equals(ancestor)) {
        // every node is an ancestor to itself
        return true;
    } else if (parent == null) {
        // not related
        return false;
    } else {
        // recursive call
        return parent.isDescendantOf(ancestor);
    }
}
```

The other way is now a piece of cake.

```
public boolean isDescendant(Node descendant) {
    return descendant.isDescendantOf(this);
}
```

No loops, no exponentional effort.

PS:
In my example i would suggest renaming `isDescendant` to `isAncestorOf`.

Comment: Of course, this only works if the nodes actually have a pointer to their parents. (If they don't have, it is worth considering adding them, if one needs this `isDescendantOf` more often than once.)

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want is below:

```
// Cleaned up version
public boolean isDescendant(member x){
    // check for direct descendance 
    if (children.contains(x)){
        return true;
    }
    // check for being descendant of the children
    for (Child c: children){
        if (children.get(i).isDescendant(x)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: that's what i did at first...but i started trying to follow it in my head and it started to not make sense. but maybe it was right?

Comment: Is it evening in here or `isDescendant(children.get(i))` will be always true? Did you mean `children.get(i).isDescendant(x)`?

Comment: @user, have you tested this.  It looks at least mostly right to me.

Comment: Just aesthetics, but you could get rid of the "else" and probably do a for-each instead. :-)

Comment: @jjnguy: this solution only checks 2 levels of children (direct and child of child). But I think question was about all levels (if some of child of any level equals to x, then x is descendant)

Comment: @llnur, this will recurse, because the call to `isDescendant` will then check the next children's children, and so on.

Comment: @aioobe, yeah I think this looks ugly too.  But I was trying to keep the code as similar to the OP as possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean isDescendant(member currentRoot, member x){
    //check the current level
    if (currentRoot.children().contains(x)){
        return true;
    }

    //leaf
    if( currentRoot.children().isEmpty() ){ return false; }

    //try all my children
    boolean found = false;
    for( Member child : currentRoot.children() ){
       found = isDescendant( child, x );
       if( found ) break;
    }

    return found;
}
```

You need to recurse over the current root, most likely.

Comment: You could modify this to be a member function by removing the iteration fo current root and calling isDescendant on each child element. I think it's clearer as a functional concept, however.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** If your data structure has parent pointers, use these instead of searching your descendants in the tree. If not, consider adding them. See the answer from whiskeysierra for a solution with parent pointers. Only if adding them is not possible, consider this answer.

---

The current answers all have two loops through children (one in `children.contains()`, one later).

This variant may be a bit more efficient (but it does not change the O-class), and is a bit shorter. (If children is a set with fast contains-check (like HashSet) and often the hierarchy is not so deep (so you don't need to recurse at all), the other answers are better.)

```
public boolean isDescendant(Member x) {
   for(Member child : children) {
      if(child.equals(x) || child.isDescendant(x))
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

If a node is considered a descendant of itself, you can write it like this:

```
public boolean isDescendant(Member x) {
   if(equals(x))
      return true;
   for(Member child : children) {
      if(child.isDescendant(x))
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```